# Why couldn't I intercept segfault signal of a child process?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, signals

I'm trying to monitor the child process for segment fault errors, but that doesn't work.

I always receive ABRT signal.

I see gdb can catch segment fault, so what's wrong with my code?

```c
        pid_t child;
        int wstatus, signum;
        struct user_regs_struct regs;

        child = fork();
        if (child == 0)
        {
                ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
                char buf[10];
                // make it always crash
                strcpy (buf, "aaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
                printf ("Buf is %s\n", buf);

                exit(0);
        }

        while(1)
        {
                wait(&wstatus);
                if (WIFEXITED(wstatus) || WIFSIGNALED(wstatus))
                        break;

                signum = WSTOPSIG(wstatus);
                ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child, NULL, &regs);

                printf ("signal: %d, eip: 0x%08lx\n", signum, regs.eip);
                ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child, NULL, signum);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

> what's wrong with my code

Your code breaks out of the loop when child is signalled (`WIFSIGNALED`). Since you are expecting to catch a signal (most likely `SIGSEGV`), perhaps you shouldn't break out of the loop when the child is signalled?

I've looked at your code some more. It is not clear why your child is crashing *at all*. Perhaps you are building it with `-fstack-protector` or some such?

Here is a complete compilable test case (which you *should* have put into your question), that does crash (note: removed `exit` from child):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/user.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t child;
    int wstatus, signum;
    struct user_regs_struct regs;

    child = fork();
    if (child == 0)
    {
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
        char buf[10];
        // make it always crash
        strcpy (buf, "aaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

        printf ("Buf is %s\n", buf);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        wait(&wstatus);
        if (WIFEXITED(wstatus))
            break;

        signum = WSTOPSIG(wstatus);
        ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child, NULL, &regs);

        printf ("signal: %d, eip: 0x%08lx\n", signum, regs.eip);
        ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child, NULL, signum);
    }
    return wstatus;
}
```

> And got infinite loop

You normally *should* get an infinite loop: you are resuming the child, which re-executes its current instruction, which should trigger the exact same signal again.

That's not what is happening with the above program on my system though, and I currently can't explain what I am observing:

```
$ ./a.out
Buf is aaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
signal: 159, eip: 0x08049ff4
signal: 159, eip: 0x08049ff4
...
signal: 159, eip: 0x08049ff4
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
signal: 11, eip: 0xf759fb19
signal: 0, eip: 0xf759fb19
signal: 0, eip: 0xf759fb19
...
```

Comment: Nope, I've tried to remove that lines. And got infinite loop, then I checked the first signal caught, was `6` (ABRT), the rest are all zeros

Comment: How do you think gdb catches segfault signals?

Comment: @warl0ck I know that GDB catches signals exactly the same way your program does. Answer updated.